# Changing style on bootstrap tabs active

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok so I'm having some issues changing the active state on my bootstrap tabs. I managed to get the hover to work but there is still some issues I am running into.

This is what I am currently using for the hover, I need the active state to be the same but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
.services-icon-holder {
border: 2px solid #272727;
border-radius: 50%;
width: 65px;
height: 65px;
margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.services-icon-holder:hover {
background-color: #272727;
cursor: pointer;
}

.services-icon {
font-size: 28px;
color: #272727;
line-height: 2.2 !important;
padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.services-icon-holder:hover .services-icon {
color: #f1f1f1;
cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.5s ease;
}
```

I also have an issue with the active tab being 1 or so pixels above the rest of the tabs, I used inspect element to try and find where this is coming from but to no success.

You can check out the [live site here](http://aliensix.com/lightningbolt) (just go to services section to see the tabs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please manage this code , this is the css structure

```
.services .nav > li > a {
  outline:none ! important;
  border: none;
}


.services .nav > li.active > a .services-icon-holder {
   background-color: #272727;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: I apologize I have been meaning to clean it up! This was actually exactly what I need to know though thank you.

Comment: Please use and think ease way ..., Thanks

Comment: Doing my best, I'm extremely new to this! Thank you for the assistance

Answer (score 1):

In `/css/style.css:517`

```
.services .nav > li > a {
  /* Add below */
  border: none;
}
```

And for active state color, you can add this code to your style

```
.nav-tabs > li.active .services-icon-holder {
    background-color: #000;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active .services-icon-holder > .services-icon {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Ah awesome, should of caught that! Any idea on the active state?

Comment: Actually what you want to do when the tab was active? Is it about tab color? In `/css/style.css:522` i'm seeing that the `background-color: transparent;`, so that the background was transparent there.

Comment: I need the active to look exactly like the hover, so when you get to the page it will look like this: http://aliensix.com/lightningbolt/services-active.jpg (don't worry about the arrow, I will battle that later)

Comment: Try again the latest one, I think I accidentally put extra `>` there before. Now should work like a charm. ;-)